# What processors should be combined to process large JSON files in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to set up a NiFi workflow that pulls large JSON documents (between 500 MB and 3 GB), that have been gzipped from an FTP server, split the JSON objects into individual flow files, and finally convert each JSON object to SQL and insert it into a MySQL database.

I am running NiFi 1.6.0, on Oracle Java 8, and Java has 1024 MB heap space set.

My current flow is:

GetFTP -> CompressContent -> SplitJson -> EvaluateJsonPath -> AttributesToJson -> ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL

This flow works great for JSON documents that are smaller. It throws `Java OutOfMemory` errors once a file that is larger than 400 MB enters the SplitJson processor. What changes can I make to the existing flow to enable it to process large JSON documents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you will want to avoid splitting to a flow file per document. You will get much better performance if you can keep many documents together in a single flow file. You will want to take a look at NiFi's record processing capabilities, specifically you will want to look at PutDatabaseRecord.

Here is a good intro to the record processing approach:
https://www.slideshare.net/BryanBende/apache-nifi-record-processing

If you absolutely have to perform splitting down to individual records per flow file, then you should at least perform a two phase split, where the first split processors splits to maybe 10k-20k per for flow file, then the second split processor splits down to 1 per flow file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of that slideshare. It makes a lot of sense to change my flow to GetFTP -> CompressContent -> PutDatabaseRecord. Configuring a JSONPathReader service took a little trial and error but is much more reusable.

Comment: Hello and thanks for this informations. Can you tell me more about the "two phase split" ? I have to use it on large Json File but I don't understand how I can split it like u suggest.